# Can`t connect to remote desktop in virtualbox machine

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, rdp, remmina

I have installed Lubuntu 20.04 in virtualbox machine and enabled Remote Desktop. Network mode is `Bridged`.

I can't connect from host (Lubuntu 21.10) to this machine with Remmina.

Vm can be ping'ed from the host, but nmap returns:

```
$ nmap 192.168.1.161 -p3389
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-05 12:12 CET
Nmap scan report for lubuntu-virtualbox.lan (192.168.1.161)
Host is up (0.00030s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

Port 3389 is open on the host, but connecting to it with remmina not work too.
How to connect to this machine ?

Comment: Is the VM’s network adapter set to “Promiscuous Mode⇢Allow All”? This is found under the Advanced settings in the VM configuration 

Comment: @matigo  Yes, it is set